# Runtime error in Python

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python.The code is a solution to a problem in one of the online judges, but it throws a runtime error. Please help me fix this code.Thanks.

```
import math
def square(n):
if n<0:
    return 0
else:
    tst=int(math.sqrt(n))
    if tst*tst==n or  (tst+1)*(tst+1)==n or (tst-1)*(tst-1)==n:
        return 1


t=input()
for i in t:

   n=input()
   flag=square(n)
   if flag==1:
       print "Case %l: Yes\n"%i

    else:
       print "Case %l: No\n"%i

    t=t-1
```

Comment: Not unless you show us the error and the traceback.

Comment: https://ideone.com/3PfwZj Here is the link to my code.

Comment: Did you read the error? It says 'i' is not defined. Which indeed is the problem.

Comment: @DanielRoseman no need to be a jerk. Suggest, don't demand.

Comment: Incidentally your 'square' method could return `None`, which is a problem. Might want to fix that.

Comment: I have updated my code now, and removed the while loop. @Sam could you tell me how to fix this, I mean even after writing a return statement, how is it possible that it returns None? It now throws the error that int object is not iterable.

Comment: @Greenleaf Your code returns 0 if `n < 0`, and returns `1` if `tst=int(math.sqrt(n))` *and* `tst*tst==n or  (tst+1)*(tst+1)==n or (tst-1)*(tst-1)==n`. In every other case, it will just reach the end of the method, returning`None` by default. I would add an explicit `return 0` as the last line of the method.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot. But still couldn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code now is that you are using `t = input()` which accepts input line by line, so the first time it just returns the first line , which is `2`.

And then you are trying to loop over it , I think instead you want to loop that much times, so you should change the code to -

```
t=int(input())
for i in range(t):
```

Using `range` function would make the loop go that much amount of times, Hoepfully that is what you intended to do.

---

When using `%` symbol for string formatting, you have to give `%d` or `%s` , etc. There does not seem to be any `%l` .

Example -

```
print "Case %d: Yes\n"%i
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot. I really forgot about the range function (still a beginner).

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the info thrown by the python interpreter:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 17, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

The line number where the error happens (17) and the type of error ('i' is not defined) appears clearly i the traceback.

Comment: I've removed the while loop now, and added the for loop, but still I get a runtime error.Now it gives 'int' object is not iterable.

Comment: The answer is the same. Read the error thrown by the interpreter. line 12, 'int' object is not iterable. You are trying to iterate throughg the values of `t` but `t` is not an iterable object. It is an integer.

Comment: In your first sample code use `t` instead of `i`. BTW, try to read a tutorial before ask this kind of question. Or at least show that you are putting some effort in resolve it.

Comment: I am sorry, I'll take note of that in the future. Thanks for the help anyway.